# Error in Robson's proof about separating strings?

Tags: automata-theory, dfa

One of my students discovered a possible mistake in Robson's classic paper [Separating strings with small automata](https://doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(89)90215-9).
The issue is in the proof of Theorem 1, giving the simpler bound $O(\sqrt{n\log n})$.
The proof goes by giving an automaton that finds a substring of length $O(\sqrt{n\log n})$ in $u$ that ends in $i$ such that $u_i\ne v_i$ is the first place where the words $u$ and $v$ differ.
It is correctly proved that the given substring cannot occur in $v$ up to $i$, starting with some required modulo, but the issue is that the substring can arise after $i$.
I think that he is right, and see no way of saving the proof.

ps. Note that the best claimed bound in Robson is $\tilde O(n^{2/5})$ recently a better bound, $\tilde O(n^{1/3})$ was proved by [Chase](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.12097).

Comment: Isn't that taken care of in the paragraph just before Theorem 1? If the accepting state is reached at some $v_j$, then we necessarily have $j>i$, and we can compose the automata with one that separates $v_{j+1}\ldots v_n$ and $u_{i+1}\ldots u_n$, which have different lengths so are easy to separate.

Comment: @Tassle You are 100% right, I've failed to notice that part. Do you want to convert your comment to an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer:

This is taken care of in the paragraph just before Theorem 1. If the accepting state is reached at some $v_j$, then we necessarily have $j>i$, and we can compose the automaton with one that separates $v_{j+1}\ldots v_n$ and $u_{i+1}\ldots u_n$, which have different lengths so are easy to separate.

Comment: Thanks Tassle. I was about to give the same answer. J.M. Robson.

Comment: I also have another question in light of this. Is it possible that any two strings can be separated in this manner in $O(\log n)$? Equivalently, given two strings of length $n$ that differ only in their last bit, can we always separate them with an $O(\log n)$ state automaton that has a unique accept state which is a sink, so once you enter it you stay there for good?

Comment: @domotorp, does this answer your question: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47292/bounds-on-this-strategy-for-separating-words

Comment: @Zach Indeed it does!

Comment: @john What is the best email to contact you at?

Comment: jrobson@u-bordeaux.fr

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30177)

Comment: @Jan The answer of Tassle was not there yet, it was only in a comment. Otherwise, I agree.